# Where in the C++11 Standard does it say that char* p = "abc"; is ill-formed?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

Where in the C++11 Standard does it say that `char* p = "abc";` is ill-formed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was still valid in C++03 (although deprecated), but things have changed in C++11. Annex C of the C++11 Standard mentions (see C1.1) that:

> **Change**: String literals made `const`
>
> The type of a string literal is changed from “array of `char`” to “array of `const char`.” The type of a
>   `char16_t` string literal is changed from “array of some-integer-type” to “array of `const char16_t`.” The
>   type of a `char32_t` string literal is changed from “array of some-integer-type” to “array of `const char32_t`.”
>   The type of a wide string literal is changed from “array of `wchar_t`” to “array of `const wchar_t`.”
>
> **Rationale**: This avoids calling an inappropriate overloaded function, which might expect to be able to
>   modify its argument.
>
> **Effect on original feature**: Change to semantics of well-defined feature.
>
> **Difficulty of converting**: Syntactic transformation. The fix is to add a cast:
>
> ```
> char* p = "abc"; // valid in C, invalid in C++
> void f(char*) {
>     char* p = (char*)"abc"; // OK: cast added
>     f(p);
>     f((char*)"def"); // OK: cast added
> }
> ```

In C++03, this was an exception to the implicit conversion rules. In C++11, this exception is gone, which is perhaps why you couldn't find the point in the Standard where this case is mentioned.

The paragraph quoted above has been added to Annex C (which is only informative, not normative) so that you could find evidence of the breaking change.

Anyway, the relevant paragraphs are 2.14.5/8:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow
>   string literal has type “**array of `n const char`**”, where `n` is the size of the string as defined below, and has
>   static storage duration (3.7).

And 4.4/1 (see also 4.2 for array-to-pointer conversions):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to `cv1 T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `cv2 T`” if “`cv2 T`” is
>   **more `cv`-qualified** than “`cv1 T`”.

Comment: Note, the Standard's example uses poor style. It would be much better in this case to explicitly specify `const_cast`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Yes, I agree

Comment: Adding to your answer the last dash in 8.5/16 we get the ill-formed statement: _Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer
expression. Standard conversions (Clause 4) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered. If the conversion cannot be done, the initialization is ill-formed._

Comment: @AndyProwl Strange, but function f() as defined above emits the following warning in VS2010: warning C4717: 'f' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil It is – the example is quite meaningless and a bit stupid.

Comment: Note that Annex C is marked "informative", not "normative". It summarizes some of the changes, but it does not make any changes.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, that is correct. I probably wasn't explicit enough about this. I edited the answer, thank you

Comment: @AndyProwl After reading your answer carefully I still don't understand why 4.4p1 is relevant to my question. For me 2.14.5p8 says it all.

Comment: @WakeupBrazil: 2.14.5/8 says string literals have type `const char[]`. 4.2 says array can decay to pointers, so `const char[]` decays to `const char*`. 4.4/1 says that a gvien pointer (in your case, `const char*`) can be converted to another pointer type (in your case, `char*`) if the target type is *more* cv-qualified than the source type. In your case it is the opposite. The target type (`char*`) is *less* cv-qualified than the source type (`const char*`). Which means the conversion is illegal.

Comment: @Potatoswatter it may be "poor style" for *you*. I prefer it, so it is "good style" for *me*. It is just a personal preference. Some like to type more for some more potential safety.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb "Some like to type more for some more potential safety…" May I suggest that as one of the leading "human compilers", you have a very unique perspective on this topic. Most people who feel that way cannot justify their opinion, and it is one that needs justification as it can lead to real software problems.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: But isn't "more potential safety" a good argument to make that kind of casts preferable in general? I thought "long-typing-casts" were the idiomatic way to write casts in C++. They are easier to search, they call attention were attention is due (a cast is usually something you don't want to go unnoticed) and they do one precise thing (so they better express the required conversion instead of saying "try this cast, if it doesn't work, try that, if it doesn't, try this and if it still doesn't work f**k it use brute force").

Comment: I think i'm not searching these keywords often in code, so that use-case does not happen to me too much. I don't say "try this, if it doesn't work, try that". But I say "do that C-style cast" :) I prefer calling their attention by putting `// ATTENTION` (good editors even syntax-hilight that or similar 'magic' words). For the purpose of casts, IMO the two parentheses and the type-name cause attention enough.

Comment: The question is how often the "potential" becomes an "actual". I believe that it is very unlikely that you cause the wrong thing by doing a c-style cast and at the same time would not have done that wrong thing by having used a c++ style cast. The internal rules for "C style" casts are quite sensibly chosen. About the only case where I use C++ style casts is when pointers-to/references-to classes are casted into different pointers-to/references-to classes.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: There are two aspects to consider here, a syntactic one and a semantic one. From the syntactic viewpoint, I could buy your argument that `// ATTENTION` is as good an attention-catcher as `static_cast<int>(...)`. Personally, if there is an attention-catcher built in the language I would prefer using that over comments. From the semantic viewpoint, I believe it is good to express minimal requirements. If I only need a `static_cast`, I would not ask for "try a `static_cast` and if it doesn't work try a `reinterpret_cast`". I'd rather be explicit about what I need exactly.

Comment: @AndyProwl *"From the semantic viewpoint, I believe it is good to express minimal requirements."* < completely agreed. But not at the cost of typing those long keywords (and they are too long for me for the benefit they have). Their benefit becomes higher for me only when inter-class casts are involved. *"I would not ask for "try a static_cast and if it doesn't work try a reinterpret_cast"* - I am not asking for that. I am asking just for a c-style cast. Whether that is implemented by the language in terms of other casts is irreleant for me. I only remember the end-result of the C-style cast.

Comment: But even they were called `rc<Type>(...)`, `sc<Type>(...)`, `cc<Type>(...)` and `dc<Type>(...)`, I would **not** use them, because while a c-style cast like `(int)foo` and `(void*)foo` are "two things", i.e int casts and pointer casts, it has the same rules in both cases - converting from one type to another type, and just the type given makes the difference. If we shorten the names of the C++ style casts as done above, we have completely different *rules* for what looks essentially the same in code.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Fair enough, I guess that is a matter of taste then. Still, most programmers are far from having your level of knowledge and awareness about what exactly are the dangers and implications of a cast. Quite often casts can be an indication of design smells. Forcing programmers to choose the exact semantics they need is at least a step towards making them aware of what they are doing, and making this bothersome helps making them think twice before using wild casts. So as a guideline I would promote `***_cast<>`. But I understand you don't need this kind of guideline :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I see the main danger of C-style casts in that it may silently change meaning when doing a code change and forgetting to change the cast (or don't notice a change in used third-party code). Imagine you've got `int const* f()` and `g(int*)`, and need to pass the return value from `f` to `g` (and you know this is actually safe; the author of `g` just didn't write const-correct code). With C-style casts you'll write `g((int*)f())`. Which works fine until the author of `f` decides that `int` is to small and returns `long long const*`. Then the C-style cast silently changes …

Comment: … into the equivalent of a `reinterpret_cast`, possibly introducing a hard to find bug. On the other hand, if you had written `g(const_cast<int*>(f()))` the compiler would have given an error, and you'd immediately know that you'll have to fix that problem. Of course, this problem cannot happen with string literals, so I'd consider the C-style cast OK in *this* case.